wp_get_nav_menu_items return only first menu item and its sub-menu items
I'm trying to retrieve first level (not sub-menus) menu items titles from a specific menu.
I tried retrieving the items using wp_get_nav_menu_items and logging them but I only get the first menu item and its children, so I can't retrieve other menu items parents.
Menu is like this:
Menu item 1  
- Sub menu 1-1  
- Sub menu 1-2  
- Sub menu 1-3

Menu item 2  
- Sub menu 2-1  
- Sub menu 2-2  
- Sub menu 2-3

Menu item 3  
- Sub menu 3-1  
- Sub menu 3-2  
- Sub menu 3-3

Logging wp_get_nav_menu_items I only get this:
- Menu item 1  
- Sub menu 1-1  
- Sub menu 1-2  
- Sub menu 1-3

This is the code I'm using:
$menu_location = 'header-mobile';
$locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
$menu_id = $locations[$menu_location];
$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu_id);

$logged_content = "Menu items:\n";

foreach ($menu_items as $menu_item) {
  $logged_content .= "- {$menu_item->title}\n";
}

error_log($logged_content);

Some other context

Menu item 1 is a custom link and its child are Wordpress Pages.
Menu item 2/3 are Woocommerce product categories with their child categories.

I also checked logging get_objects_in_term and I get all the menu items with their ids but that's not usable because there is no hierarchy.
So why wp_get_nav_menu_items is not retrieving all items?
